# How to get z-score distribution for 3 dataframes and plot all in one graph

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I'm trying to create a single graph that contains boxplots of gene expression for 3 different variant types (synonymous, missense, and nonsense). Currently, these variant types are separated into 3 different data frames, each of which contain a `Gene`, `SampleID`, and `Expression` column.

In order to plot all 3 boxplots on a single graph, I need to normalize all the expression data for each variant type, which means I need to get the z-scores. My question is, how do I do that and then how do I plot all 3 variant types on one graph?

I've come across the solution:

```
missense$Zscore <- ave(m$expr, m$Gene, FUN = scale)
nonsense$Zscore <- ave(n$expr, n$Gene, FUN = scale)
synonymous$Zscore <- ave(s$expr, s$Gene, FUN = scale)
```

Is this the right approach? If so, where do I go from here?

Example dataframe (missense):

```
SampleID     Expression   Gene       
HSB100       5.239237     ENSG00000188976 
HSB105       4.443808     ENSG00000188976
HSB104       4.425764     ENSG00000188976
HSB121       4.063259     ENSG00000188976
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `boxplot(list(missense$Zscore, nonsense$Zscore, synonymous$Zscore))`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scale` function to get Z-scores.

```
missense <- data.frame(SampleID = c('HSB100', 'HSB105', 'HSB104', 'HSB121'),
                    Expression = c(5.239237, 4.443808, 4.425764, 4.063259),
                    Gene = c('ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976'))
missense$Zscore <- scale(missense$Expression)

missense

mean(missense$Zscore)
sd(missense$Zscore)

# Create fake data here

nonsense <- 
        data.frame(SampleID = c('HSB100', 'HSB105', 'HSB104', 'HSB121'),
                   Expression = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   Gene = c('ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976'))
nonsense$Zscore <- scale(nonsense$Expression)
synonymous <- 
        data.frame(SampleID = c('HSB100', 'HSB105', 'HSB104', 'HSB121'),
                   Expression = c(3, 4, 5, 6),
                   Gene = c('ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976', 'ENSG00000188976'))
synonymous$Zscore <- scale(synonymous$Expression)
```

The trick is to bind all three data frames together and then plot using ggplot.  Not familiar with base plot but this is what I would do:

```
# Add identifyer

missense$Type <- 'missense'
nonsense$Type <- 'nonsense'
synonymous$Type <- 'synonymous'


# Bind three together

data_all <- rbind(missense, nonsense, synonymous)

# Use ggplot to plot boxscores

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data_all, aes(x = Type, y = Zscore)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the genes are the same in each corresponding data frame, then `ave` is not needed since no multiple groupings exist. Hence, you can run a simple calculation: `m$Zscore <- scale(m$expr)`. From there as @emilliman5 comments, graph all three vectors with a list and even name x-axis with a named list:

```
# WITH SEABORN COLORS
boxplot(list(missense=m$Zscore, nonsense=n$Zscore, synonymous=s$Zscore),
        col = c("#4c72b0","#55a868","#c44e52"))
```

Even consider row binding all data frames but adding a new column for a *variant_type* indicator. Then use `ave` since now genes will differ within data frame. And even use formula style instead of `list()` for `boxplot`:

```
all_gene_df <- rbind(transform(m, variant_type='missense'), 
                     transform(n, variant_type='nonsense'), 
                     transform(s, variant_type='synonymous'))

all_gene_df$Zscore <- with(all_gene_df, ave(expr, variant_type, FUN = scale))

# WITH SEABORN COLORS
boxplot(Zscore ~ variant_type, data = all_gene_df,
        col = c("#4c72b0","#55a868","#c44e52"),
        main = "ZScore Boxplots by Gene",
        xlab = "Genes",
        ylab = "ZScore")
```

[image: Box Plot Output]

**Data**

```
set.seed(103018)
m <- data.frame(SampleID = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE),
                                  sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(100:999, 50, replace=TRUE)),
                expr = runif(50)*10,
                gene = 'MISSENSE0001')

n <- data.frame(SampleID = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE),
                                  sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(100:999, 50, replace=TRUE)),
                expr = runif(50)*10,
                gene = 'NONSENSE0001')

s <- data.frame(SampleID = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE),
                                  sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), sample(100:999, 50, replace=TRUE)),
                expr = runif(50)*10,
                gene = 'SYNONYMOUS0001')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I did `m_genes = as.character(unique(missense$Gene))` as well as for the other 2 dataframes, and the number of unique genes varies between the three of them. So I guess I have to use `ave`

Comment: Understood. So you have multiple genes between your three variant types. Then, yes, use `ave` as originally or still after `rbind`. However, you will not be running 3 boxplots but as many distinct *gene* you have. Maybe consider adding an indicator in each before `rbind`. See edit.

Comment: Gotcha. And if I wanted to get each gene's Z-score for each sample, would it be: `ave(m$Expression, m$Gene, m$SampleID, FUN = scale)`?

Comment: Sure. Add as many groupings as needed in `ave` with first argument being numeric vector to process and last argument being the function.